# Is it possible to use HttpModule to authenticate for SignalR

Tags: asp.net, authentication, signalr, owin, httpmodule

I am developing an application that uses an HttpModule to perform custom authentication and authorization. My problem is that the user Identity set in the HttpModule is not accessible in the SignalR context objects.

I do the following in my HttpModule BeginRequest handler after custom authentication logic:

```
var userClaims = new List<Claim>();
userClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, <some id>));
userClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, <some name>));
userClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, <da email>));
userClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Authentication, "true"));

var id = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new[] { id });
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

I thought that this would absolutely make everything hereafter behave as though the request was authenticated, however this is not the case.

I have created a SignalR AuthorizeAttribute class to handle the authentication that looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.StartsWith("/signalr/connect"))
        {
            var test = (ClaimsPrincipal)HttpContext.Current.User;
            var test2 = (ClaimsPrincipal)Thread.Current.Principal;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubContext, bool appliesToMethod)
    {
        var test = (ClaimsPrincipal)hubContext.Hub.Context.User;
        return true;
    }
}
```

So my plan was to access the hubContext.Hub.Context.User var from within the AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation method to do any custom authorization I needed. However this just contains the default WindowsPrincipal.

If I look into the AuthorizeHubConnection call (which is actually a regular HTTP request and not a websocket call), I see that the HttpContext.Current object also does not have the User set as it should.

I do see that I can access the HttpContext.Current.Items collection. I presume I could use this to toss the Principal from the module to the SignalR context, but I'm not sure that is what I'm supposed to do.

Is it best to simply rewrite the HttpModule as OWIN middleware? It looks like I'll have to change stuff anyways when/if we update to ASP.NET 5; there's nothing like MS products to give you job security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot I posted this question a while ago. I ended up explaining my solution in a comment on the MS article [Authentication and Authorization for SignalR Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization). After trying to implement OWIN middleware for auth I found I would have to do some goofy config to run all modules for all requests, which is inefficient. I couldn't figure out how to run just the Auth OWIN middleware component for all requests so I abandoned that approach and stuck with my HttpModule. Here is a summary of my solution for SignalR auth posted on the page linked above:

1) Create a AuthorizeAttribute class like indicated in the article:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
```

2) Decorate your Hub class with the auth class you created. The naming convention appears to be (SomeName)Attribute for the auth class itself and (SomeName) for the hub decoration.

```
[CustomAuth]
public class ServerWebSocket : Hub
```

3) Instead of overriding the "UserAuthorized" method as shown in the docs, override the following methods (I got this from some other SO post, but I can't find it right now):

```
public override bool AuthorizeHubConnection(HubDescriptor hubDescriptor, IRequest request)
public override bool AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation(IHubIncomingInvokerContext hubContext, bool appliesToMethod)
```

In order to actually authorize users I catch SignalR connection requests in my HttpModule and set an item in the HttpContext Items collection like so:

```
if (req.Path.StartsWith("/signalr/connect") || req.Path.StartsWith("/signalr/reconnect"))
{
    var user_info = doFullAuth(<some token>);
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("userDat", user_info);
}
```

This is actually set up so that connect requests will be completely rejected in the HttpModule if the user doesn't have permission. So I actually don't implement the SignalR auth method "AuthorizeHubConnection" at all. But in the "AuthorizeHubMethodInvocation" method I access the user data by calling HttpContext.Current.Items that was set on the original connect request and do custom logic to determine if a method can be accessed by the user.

This is the best way I can figure to get it to work if you want to authenticate every request to protect static files and such.